# How to build SQL Query executed in VBA?

Tags: sql, vba

I made the following group by query :

```
SQL = " SELECT DISTINCTROW [A], [B], [C],[D], Sum([E]) AS [Sum E]" & _
      " FROM [SheetName$RangeAddress]" & _
      " GROUP BY [A], [B], [C],[D];"
```

This returns a too large amount of data where I wish to have only the TOP 5 so I tried the following:

```
SQL = " SELECT TOP 5 FROM (SELECT DISTINCTROW [A], [B], [C],[D], Sum([E]) AS [Sum E]" & _
      " FROM [SheetName$RangeAddress]" & _
      " GROUP BY [A], [B], [C],[D]) ORDER BY [Sum E] DESC;"
```

This throws the following error:

> The SELCT Statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that
> is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SQL = " SELECT TOP 5 * FROM" & _
      "     (SELECT DISTINCTROW [A], [B], [C], [D], Sum([E]) AS [Sum E]" & _
      "     FROM [SheetName$RangeAddress]" & _
      "     GROUP BY [A], [B], [C], [D]) AS T"
      " ORDER BY T.[Sum E] DESC;"
```